# XMLHttpRequest to the MongoDB simple rest interface

Tags: javascript, ajax, mongodb

I am a beginner in both Ajax and MongoDB. I was hoping to visualize some of the data in my MongoDB using a web browser (which, for the moment, is running on the same host). For this, I thought it might be possible to get the data using XMLHttpRequests. I am running MongoDB with the --rest option and I checked that when I load hxxp://localhost:28017/test_db/ss_test/
on Firefox, I get the proper reply (a JSON document with the data in the ss_test collection of the test_db database). So far, so good.

I then wrote the following JavaScript function which I connected to the "onclick" of a button:

```
function makeRequest()
{
  var myrequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  myrequest.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    alert("status=" + myrequest.status + " readyState=" + myrequest.readyState)
    if (myrequest.status == 200 && myrequest.readyState == 4)
    {
      // ...do something with the response
    }
  }    
myrequest.open("GET", "http://localhost:28017/test_db/ss_test/", true);
myrequest.send();
}
```

So, when I load the html file on Firefox, open the console and click on my button, I see that the http request is indeed made, the status code is "HTTP/1.0 200 OK" and a response with Content-Length: 219257 is delivered, which looks great. However, the XMLHttpRequest object does not report the status=200. The alerts that pop up report a constant status of 0 as the readyState progressively becomes 1, 2 and 4 and my if statement is never true.

Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong? In the beginning I thought it was because my html was loaded on the browser by the file protocol or that I was seeing some same-origin policy related issue, but then I put the html file on a web server on localhost and loaded it from there and nothing changed. Thank you very much for any replies!

Comment: The http code 0 does not exist. Use a sniffer like **tamper data**, to see what http status code you are actually receiving.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a function to handle the request.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ajaxintro2/

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ajaxintro3/

```
function makeRequest()
{
  var myrequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  myrequest.onreadystatechange = create_this_function()
  {

  }    
myrequest.open("GET", "http://localhost:28017/test_db/ss_test/", true);
myrequest.send();
}
```

#

```
function create_this_function()
{
    alert("status=" + myrequest.status + " readyState=" + myrequest.readyState)
    if (myrequest.status == 200 && myrequest.readyState == 4)
    {
      // ...do something with the response
    }
}
```